# Best way to have several arrays as optional parameters in a php function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a function that has the following header (part of a simple pdo wrapper class):

`function select($table_name, $fields = [], $where = [])`

It gets awkward when I have a *where* clause but I want to use the default value for the fields, as in a call like this:

```
  $where = array(
    'Username'    =>  $username,
    'Password'    =>  $encrypted_password
  );

  // Select all fields from User with the where clause above
  $STMT = $dbpdo->select("User", [], $where);`
```

This is a just an example to illustrate the question. What is the most elegant way to use this type of construct in php? Ideally I would like to use a call like:

`$dbpdo->select("User", $where);`

or

`$dbpdo->select("User", $fields, $where);`

Comment: feeling a bit of opinion based..., i might go for `$pdo->table("user")->select("username, password")->where("a")...."`

Comment: Hi @Andrew its more a "different ways to solve this problem" kind of question. Regarding your solution, that is an excellent call but in this specific case I need to use a separate class. Also, the pdo case is an example to a broader one, that is, having several arrays as parameters and how to deal with them in an elegant way. Thanks!

Comment: If you call it with just two arguments argument, how is it supposed to know if the second argument is `$fields` or `$where`?

Comment: That's the whole point of the question @Barmar. There are several ways to accomplish this, I am wondering which ways my fellow coders have used/read before

Comment: You can really only do this type of thing when the optional arguments are of different types. Then you can test the type of the argument to determine which one was supplied and which one should get a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use `func_get_args()` and `func_num_args()` to handle the two-paramter and three-parameter calls to your function differently, but I would not recommend this, as it would make your function potentially confusing for others to use.

Personally, I think `$dbpdo->select("User", [], $where);` is just fine.

You might also consider swapping the $where and $fields parameters, if it's more likely that $fields is going to have its default/empty value.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's fine too, i have seen this kind of construct in several different php frameworks, but I was wondering if there might be a better way. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since you pointed me to func_get_args() which I find will be useful in the future. Thanks!